# How can I write text from variables in front of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working on a card maker app. The idea behind it is to have a CSV file with data for each card, a folder with images, and to create a card for each character I have once the CSV file is uploaded. So far so good, but I am stucked in writing the text in front of the canvas.

The canvas is created by overlapping a lot of different images, but the text appears on the very background and ends up being entirely covered by the other images. I want texts to be in front of it!

I trigger everything upon the loading of the CSV file containing the data, and I actually use a  "*context.fillText*" but is not working as I want it to work.

How can I put the text from the variables inside the last 3 "context.fillText" on front of the canvas?
The final scope is to have a single canvas I can save as an image.

**And this is my code**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
      var images = {};
      var loadedImages = 0;
      var numImages = 0;
      // get num of sources
      for(var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
      }
      for(var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function() {
          if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
            callback(images);
          }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
      }

    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


  document.getElementById('txtFileUpload').addEventListener('change', upload, false);
  
  function upload(evt) {
      var file = evt.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onload = function (event) {
          var csvData = event.target.result;
          Papa.parse(csvData, {
              complete: function (results) {
                  console.log(results.data);
              
                  var imgStelle;
                  var imgClan;
                  var immagine;

                  var numeroCarte=(results.data.length);
                  for(var i=0; i<numeroCarte; i++){
                    
                      var clan=(results.data[i][0]);
                      var nome =(results.data[i][1]); 
                      var rarita =(results.data[i][2]);
                      var stelle =(results.data[i][3]);
                      var potenza =(results.data[i][4]);
                      var danno =(results.data[i][5]);
                      var potere =(results.data[i][6]);
                      var bonus=(results.data[i][7]);
                      var nomeintero=(results.data[i][8]);

                      imgStelle = "Immagini/LivelloCarte/livello"+ stelle +".png";
                      imgClan= "Immagini/IconeClan/"+ clan +"_42.png";
                      if (rarita=="Non comune"){
                          imgRarita = "Immagini/RaritaCarta/raritanoncomune.png";
                      } else {
                          imgRarita = "Immagini/RaritaCarta/rarita"+rarita+".png";
                      }
                  
                      immagine ="Immagini/ImmaginiChar/"+clan+"_"+nomeintero+"_N"+stelle+"_HD_673.png"
                  
                      var sources = {
                          image1: 'Immagini/SfondoCarte/base.png',
                          image2:'Immagini/SfondoCarte/riquadro.png',
                          image3: immagine,
                          image4:'Immagini/SfondoCarte/poteri.png',
                          image5: imgRarita,
                          image6: imgStelle,
                          image7: 'Immagini/SfondoCarte/riquadrobis.png',
                          image8: imgClan,
                          image9: 'Immagini/Numeri/'+potenza+'.png',
                          image10:'Immagini/Numeri/'+danno+'.png',
                        };

                        loadImages(sources, function(images) {
                          context.drawImage(images.image1, 0, 0,  2220 , 3240);  //SFONDO *   x - y
                          context.drawImage(images.image2, 80, 80,  2040 ,1900);//RIQUADRO
                          context.drawImage(images.image3, 0, 0,  2220 ,3150);  //IMMAGINE *
                          context.drawImage(images.image4, 80, 2000,  2050 ,1150);  //LAYOUT POTERI *
                          context.drawImage(images.image5, 520, 80,  1610 ,200);   //RARITA *
                          context.drawImage(images.image6, 600, 2000,  1240 ,260);  //STELLE *
                          context.drawImage(images.image7, 100, 70,  360 ,360);  //RIQUADRO CLAN *
                          context.drawImage(images.image8, 120, 80,  320 ,320);  //CLAN *
                          context.drawImage(images.image9, 170, 2350,  130 ,170);  //FORZA *
                          context.drawImage(images.image10, 170, 2950,  130 ,170);  //DANNO *
                        });

                        context.font = "40pt Calibri";
                        context.fillText(nome, 20, 20);
                        context.fillText(potere, 20, 20);
                        context.fillText(bonus, 20, 20);

                  
                  }
              }
          });
      };
  }
      

});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Pagina.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="Pagina.js"></script> 
    <script src="papaparse.js"></script> 
    <script src="papaparse.min.js"></script> 

    <title>Card maker</title>                             
  
  </head>


  <body>

    <input type="file" name="File Upload" id="txtFileUpload" accept=".csv" />

    <div class="cartaSingola">
        <div class="contenitoreCarte">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="2500" height="3500"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you supply an example CSV so we can try your code? Or maybe modify the code to run with some predefined values.

Comment: The CSV structure is easy, just a tons of rows with the same pattern but different values:
ClanName,CardName,1,1,1,CardPower,CardBonus,FullName

Comment: What about you put the text inside a new html `<div>` and position it in front of the canvas using CSS?

Comment: @Papooch but then you'll lose the "save as image" capabilities. @OP I'm getting `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Papa is not defined"`, can you properly include this?

Comment: @Stratubas Papa is the js of an external library called papaparse :)

Comment: Yes, they should have some public CDN url to import it though, no?

Comment: I just went straight to their "download" section to get the files, because I wasn't finding any CDN. Here the site: https://www.papaparse.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're drawing the images in your "all images have loaded" callback, but the text is drawn before this callback is run.

Try this instead:

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    context.drawImage(images.image1, 0, 0,  2220 , 3240);
    // context.drawImage image2, 3, ...9,
    context.drawImage(images.image10, 170, 2950,  130 ,170);

    // Draw text here
    context.font = "40pt Calibri";
    context.fillText(nome, 20, 20);
    context.fillText(potere, 20, 20);
    context.fillText(bonus, 20, 20);
});
```

and also replace `var` with `const` here:

```
const nome = results.data[i][1]; 
const potere = results.data[i][6];
const bonus = results.data[i][7];
```

Comment: @GianlucaFontana Doesn't work as in "doesn't draw anything" or still draws behind the images?

Comment: @GianlucaFontana I wouldn't be surprised if it painted the wrong texts either...

Comment: @GianlucaFontana try replacing `var` with `const`, as I added in my answer.

Comment: Sir, you cracked the case. Thanks a lot, really! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.append()` and create text inside `.contenitoreCarte` or even you canvas

the usage is too simple,
here the document:
https://api.jquery.com/append/

If you give me an example of your CSV I can submit a better answer by completing your code

Comment: In this way I won't be able to save it as image.